# Magento - uniquely referencing order items during one page checkout

Tags: product, checkout, onepage-checkout, controllers, downloadable

The store I am working on is for downloadable products only. During the checkout if we have a book of a particular attribute set we send a SOAP request to an external company (to get the ebook's downloadable URL from the external company). I have wrote a module which overrides the `saveOrderAction` of the `OnepageController.php`

I have created an extra database table which stores the information about the item's downloadable URL which is updated on the `saveOrderAction`.

As during the checkout the Order ID isn't generated I have created an Observer which checks for the order being saved event, during this it finds the Order ID of the current products which I update the database table I created.

The problem I'm having now is how to update the downloadable URLs when the user clicks download on their downloadable products section of their customer account.

In the `DownloadController.php` I have found the function `linkAction` which I believe is called when the download button is clicked for an product. In there I have `print_r` the `$linkPurchasedItem` variable which shows an `purchased_id` and `item_id` which appear to be unique for the product.

To return the downloadable URL which is saved in the database (on my custom table) and given from the external company I will need to update the database table I have created at some point to insert the 'purchased_id' or 'item_id' so in the `DownloadController.php` on the `linkAction` I can run another database call to get the right downloadable URL for the product this function is being called for.

Therefore my questions are:

- At what point is the `purchased_id` and/or `item_id` generated?
- Is it possible to get them in the `OnepageController.php`?
- What is the best way to uniquely identify each product in each order in my custom database table so I can reference it in the `DownloadController.php`?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your main questions, in order:

**1. At what point is the `purchased_id` and/or `item_id` generated?**

Both `purchased_id` and `item_id` are generated within `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Observer` from the method `saveDownloadableOrderItem`. This observer is registered to listen for the event `sales_order_item_save_commit_after` - which is called every time an order item is saved and the db transaction commit has completed.

The specific line where this is set is ~105*:

```
$linkPurchasedItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')
    ->setPurchasedId($linkPurchased->getId())
    ->setOrderItemId($orderItem->getId());
```

This happens just before it generates the hash for the download link. You'll see that it does not explicitly set the `item_id` - indeed, it isn't necessary because it is the autoincrement primary key for the table.

In summary, *the ids are set after the order item is successfully saved to the database, meaning the order itself is also saved.*

**2. Is it possible to get them in the OnepageController.php?**

Because the order item has to be saved in order to generate the `purchased_id`, the answer is no.

**3. What is the best way to uniquely identify each product in each order in my custom database table so I can reference it in the DownloadController.php?**

In much the same way as shown above in the model setter `setOrderItemId`, they used the sales order item's id to reference that particular product. You should also use this strategy. In order to inject this into your own table, rewrite `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Observer` to save to your own table in parallel to the save in the downloadable tables -- otherwise you'll have to copy the pattern set forth in that class, doing many checks to ensure that the product type id is Downloadable, etc.

**Summary:**

You're not going to be able to generate download links from your SOAP service until after the order is completed. Without a major refactor there is no way to access `purchased_id` in Onepage.php.

---

<sub>* at least in CE 1.8 Alpha / EE 1.13.0.1</sub>